# Get rid of small circles above each letter in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

Whenever I try to type any letter in MS word I seem to get a small circle above each letter. Clearing the formatting removes these dot. However I have a document with many formats. Is there any way I can remove these without clearing the text format?

[image: Image for reference]

Comment: This looks like a feature to show leading and kerning. Have you tried adjusting letter spacing, or using special fonts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried the following solution in my Word document. Please give it a try.

Go into the font settings
Under the "Alt Text" section, check if there is a dot selected under the "Emphasis Mark" dropdown.
If so, clear that and save the default if you want it to stick for new documents as well.

Ensure that all the text is selected where you want to remove the dot.

Please let me know if this fixes it!

Comment: This was the issue. For anyone who stumbles upon this and can't find emphasis mark, you have to enable Asian language support. On windows, I install Chinese (Simplified, China), restarted word and it was visible